# How are factory constructors supposed to be done in Swift?

Tags: swift, factory

The Swift developers seem to be saying that polymorphism should be accomplished via protocols, not class inheritance. For example, let's say you have an array of Shapes and the Shapes have different draw methods, `Shape` should be a protocol not a superclass.

```
protocol Shape {
    func draw()
}

class Circle: Shape {
    func draw() { print("Drawing a circle") }
}

class Triangle: Shape {
    func draw() { print("Drawing a triangle") }
}

var shapes = [Shape]()

func fillShapes() {
    //... Add circles and triangles to shapes ...
}

// run
fillShapes()
for shape in shapes {
    shape.draw()
}
```

Now say you want to build Shapes based on user input which produces Strings. How would you write a Shape constructor that accepts String as input, in the most Swift-y way?

Cristik in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753997/swift-creating-a-factory-function-that-takes-a-class-type-as-a-parameter-and-o) suggests a global function like this:

```
func buildShape(kind: String) -> Shape? {
    switch kind {
        case "Circle": return Circle()
        case "Triangle": return Triangle()
        default: return nil // Error - bad Shape
    }
}
```

This seems messy to me. I would rather the constructor was incorporated into `Shape`.

So my first attempt was

```
extension Shape {
    static func build(kind: String) -> Shape? {
        switch kind {
            case "Circle": return Circle()
            case "Triangle": return Triangle()
            default: return nil // Error - bad Shape
        }
    }
}
```

But calling `Shape.build("Circle")!` produces `error: static member 'build' cannot be used on instance of type 'Shape.Protocol'`

I also tried

```
extension Shape {
    class Factory {
        func build(string: String) -> Shape? {
            switch kind {
                case "Circle": return Circle()
                case "Triangle": return Triangle()
                default: return nil
            }
        }
    }
    static let factory = Factory()
}

shapes.append(Shape.factory.build("Circle")!)
```

But it says Factory cannot be defined inside a protocol extension.

How does Swift want us to make flexible constructors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do for a Factory method on Shape, neither a protocol nor a super class should know details about implementations or derived classes. I'd rather go for a ShapeBuilding protocol and a factory class.

```
protocol Shape {
    func draw()
}

protocol ShapeBuilding {
    static func build(kind:String) -> Shape?
}

struct ShapeBuilder: ShapeBuilding {
    static func build(kind: String) -> Shape? {
        switch kind {
        case "Circle": return Circle()
        case "Triangle": return Triangle()
        default: return nil // Error - bad Shape
        }
    }
}
let circle = ShapeBuilder.build("Circle")
```

Motto: Just because Swift offers extensions we don't have to force everything into extension.

Comment: I agree with your motto, and your answers have helped me understand protocol extensions better. I don't understand the point of your `ShapeBuilding` protocol, though. Thanks.

Comment: And you're right also that `Shape` shouldn't know about `Circle`s and how to construct them.

Comment: It is always beneficial to code against protocols, as this would allow your to easily exchange with another type implementing the protocol. You might want to have specialized versions. Or in unit testing you could implement an independent mock.

Answer (score 4):

You are overthinking the problem. There is nothing cleaner than a "global" function.

The problem with global functions in some languages is that they are polluting the global namespace which leads to name conflicts.

However, every Swift project has its own namespace and every framework it imports has also its own namespace, so there is no problem with name conflicts, thus, there is nothing wrong with global functions.

There is no need to wrap simple functions into Factory classes just to create an illusion of a namespace (this would be the correct solution in Java because you cannot create a global function in Java).

Function accessed as `Shape.Factory.build(...)` is not any better than a function accessed using `buildShape(...)`.

If you really want to have a namespace, you can just wrap your functions into a `struct`:

```
struct Shapes {
    static func buildShape(kind: String) -> Shape? {
        switch kind {
        case "Circle": return Circle()
        case "Triangle": return Triangle()
        default: return nil // Error - bad Shape
        }
    }
}
```

and call it as `Shapes.buildShape(...)` but there is not real need for it.

Comment: Yes. I think you are right that `shapes` is where this should go if it can't be left naked. `shapes` will be a singleton, so it will take some thought...

Comment: I've just realized that my ancient abhorrence of "global" comes from other issues that are obsolete as well. For example, one issue with global was deciding where to put it and being able to find it later.  With modern IDEs finding it is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 3):

The protocol cannot (and in my personal opinion, should not) be used as a "factory".

A protocol is a set of rules that a construct follows, not a concrete construct itself. A factory should be a concrete type, not a "set of rules". The solution is to have a separate `ShapeFactory` construct (be it a `class`, `struct` or `enum`), with static/non-static `build` functions.

As for the "messy" part; I agree. It is kind of messy. Swift doesn't isn't capable of things like `struct Shape.Factory { }`. There's no real way to get around it without making a compromise / rewriting the compiler, the latter of which can actually be achieved with some good constructive criticism at the [swift-evolution](https://lists.swift.org/mailman/listinfo/swift-evolution) mailing list.

Comment: I agree with you now. And I think maybe Swift doesn't want a solution to it, because it doesn't want protocols to facilitate abstract class hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

All three of you have given me good insight into this question. I now see that it is a much deeper question than I first imagined.

Here is my consolidated answer.

The Swift message is **Avoid Building Abstract Class Hierarchy**. Protocols are glue (or grease maybe?) not abstract superclasses.

In Swift, a protocol like `Shape` is not an abstract superclass of Circle and Triangle in the Java sense. Don't try to put factory constructors (constructors that can return more than one type) into protocols.

The previous version of this post suggested that `shapes` could hold the differentiated construction code. But I have changed my mind. `shapes` shouldn't know about circles and triangles either. `shapes` is polymorphic and that's what polymorphic means. Therefore I have substantially changed this post. If there was strike-through I would use it but I don't see it.

I now think a global function like this is the right way.

```
func buildShapeFrom(userInput: String) -> Shape? {
    switch userInput {
        case "Circle": return Circle()
        case "Triangle": return Triangle()
        default: return nil // Error - bad input
    }
}
```

If there's an appropriate structure on the user input side, perhaps it could go there. The user cares whether it is a circle or a triangle, but `Shape` shouldn't and neither should `shapes`.

Comments welcome.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11830622)

Comment: Thanks. I'll get the hang of this eventually.